# SQL Ignores Nested Case

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, case

I'm creating a Date_Dimension and have the Problem that i have to define "lastworkingdayofmonth" with Setting a flag on it.

I can handle all days but when the calculated they is a Holiday i cant get the day before to set the flag.

Please help me :)

```
UPDATE  DATE_DIMENSION_001
SET     ISLASTWORKINGDAYMONTH = 
        CASE    WHEN ( CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), lastdayofmonth, 112) = Datekey ) AND IsWeekday = 1 AND IsHolidayAut = 0 THEN 1
                WHEN ( CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), dbo.fn_LastWorkday(FullDate), 112) ) = Datekey AND IsHolidayAut = 0 THEN 1
                WHEN ( CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), dbo.fn_LastWorkday(FullDate), 112) ) = Datekey AND IsHolidayAut = 1 THEN
                    CASE WHEN ( DATEADD(DD, -1, dbo.fn_LastWorkday(FullDate)) ) = CONVERT(DATE, Datekey) THEN 1
                    END
        END
```

Comment: what is your expected output and what you getting right now ?

Comment: one thing i want to notice here that, you have not handle Else part for both the case statement. It would be a safe side of you code when handle Else part properly in case when statement.

Comment: i want to set the flag on the column "Islastworkingday" for 10 years i get 117 months i should get 120 and the other 3 are after my Research Holidays so the nested case should check this but somehow it's ignored i think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that something like this may work for you:

```
UPDATE  dd
SET     ISLASTWORKINGDAYMONTH = 1
FROM
   DATE_DIMENSION_001 dd
     left join
   DATE_DIMENSION_001 dd_anti
     on
        DATEPART(year,dd.FullDate) = DATEPART(year,dd_anti.FullDate) and
        DATEPART(month,dd.FullDate) = DATEPART(month,dd_anti.FullDate) and
        dd_anti.FullDate > dd.FullDate and
        dd_anti.IsWeekday = 1 and
        dd_anti.IsHolidayAut = 0
WHERE
    dd.IsWeekday = 1 and
    dd.IsHolidayAut = 0 and
    dd_anti.FullDate is null
```

That is, we locate rows which are weekdays, not holidays, and for which (via `dd_anti`, the `LEFT JOIN` and the `null` check in the `WHERE` clause) we cannot locate another row for the same month, but a later date, and is also a weekday and not a holiday.

Comment: Couldn't get it work it just sets 1 in 2019 and nothing between 2010 and 2018 why?

Comment: @SerkanArslan - ah, oops. We should have a `year` test in the join conditions also. I'll edit that in.

Comment: thx it worked now fine :) im so happy thx bro :D @Damien_The_Unbeliever do you know how i can do the same with quarter can i do it just changing month to quarter?

Comment: @SerkanArslan - `DATEPART` can return quarters as well, so you could replace the line that checks for "the same month": `DATEPART(month,dd.FullDate) = DATEPART(month,dd_anti.FullDate)` with one that means "the same quarter": `DATEPART(quarter,dd.FullDate) = DATEPART(quarter,dd_anti.FullDate)`.

Comment: YES, changing to quarter answered my question above and I want to say again THANKS A LOT to you for this Code it does a great work :)